# not able to connect postgresql after 30 connections

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I have 2 cloud servers of postgresql, 1st one is working fine but in second after 30 mins i am not able to connect from java application. When i connect from pgadmin it shows 30 to 40 connection and after killing those connection every thing runs smooth.
its

**configuration:**
postgresql/9.3

max_connections = 100

shared_buffers = 4GB

When same application is connect to other postgresql with same schema every thing **works fine forever**

**Configuration:**
postgresql/9.1

max_connections = 100

shared_buffers = 32MB

Can u please help me to understand or fix the issue

Comment: Why d oyou have 30-40 connections open? Are they all from your application?

Comment: Yes all are from my application
 but limit is 100 so it should not be issue

Comment: Why is your application (I assume it's one instance) leaving 40 connections open? Either way you're probably logging in with pgadmin as root, try psql with the same user as your app if you can't catch the error in your app.

Comment: I tried to connect to database using application, pgadmin and other tools. Once i log off from application i can see connection is in sleeping state. Shouldn't it terminate ?

Answer (score 0):

I work on a PostgreSQL 9.3 instance with hundreds of open connections.  I concur to you that the open connections themselves shouldn't be a problem.  Sine we don't have much information, what follows is a description of how to get started troubleshooting.

1. Check server logs for anything wrong.  Maybe there is an issue on the OS level with initiating connections?
2. Try logging in with psql as the application user.  Does the problem persist?  If not, the problem is not with PostgreSQL.  I would take a closer look at the Java code and see if something is happening there.
3. Note that psql and other libpq actions may not give you the full picture.  Try connecting locally over a non-SSL connection while watching a packet capture.  You can find (and look up) the SQLSTATE error of the connection in this case.  This is because, for legacy and backwards compatibility reasons libpq does not pass the sqlstate up to the client app when connecting to the database.

My bet though is that this is not a postgresql issue.  It may be an operating system issue.  It may be a resource issue.  It may be a client application issue.